# How can I get rid of the automatically generating <span> tags?

Tags: posts

I am creating a post in Wordpress and every time I switch to the visual editor, a `<span>` tag is generated automatically.

Every one of them are the same, except SCXW104349300 in the code below:

```
R<span class="TextRun SCXW104349300" lang="EN-US" xml:lang="EN-US"><span class="NormalTextRun SCXW104349300">equired. Username used to authenticate the proxy server</span></span>
```

For the word "Required", a `<span>` tag between "R" and "equired" is frustrating.

The visual editor seems easy-to-use for larger posts with a lot of bolds and italics, but it seems a table cannot be created in the Visual editor, so I am switching back and forth between visual and text editors, and then I noticed this.

Is there any way I can get rid of this?

Comment: These don’t look like WP would normally create. I would look if there is an editor–related plugin that might be responsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a child theme, just add this function to your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'foobar_setup', 11 );
function foobar_setup() {
  global $editor_styles;
  $editor_styles = array();
}
```

This works for me for details follow below links which I used as source of this solution :

[This post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/span-tags-keep-getting-inserted-automatically/)  and [another one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/strange-behaviour-making-lists-in-the-visual-editor/)